# copyToRealmOrUpdate clears RealmList

Tags: android, realm

I have some troubles with RealmLists when I want to update an object and I can't find a solution.
I know there is a similar subject but it didn't have an answer.

Here are my two classes :

```
public class Category extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private long id;

private String label;

private boolean isIncome;

private double defaultBudget;

private boolean isArchived;

private RealmList<Amount> amounts;

private RealmList<AutomaticTransaction> automaticTransactions;

}

public class Amount extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private long id;

private Category category;

private int day;

private Month month;

private String label;

private double amount;
}
```

I update the category by creating a new category with the older attributes and then I set the new values

```
Category updatedCategory = category.getUpdatedCategory();
updatedCategory.setLabel(labelEditText.getText().toString());
updatedCategory.setDefaultBudget(budget);
databaseHandler.addOrUpdateCategory(updatedCategory);

public Category getUpdatedCategory(){
    return(new Category(id, label, isIncome, defaultBudget, amounts, 
    automaticTransactions));
}
```

Before the transaction, the list is full, after it's empty, I don't understand why.

```
 public void addOrUpdateCategory(final Category category){
    Log.e("test",category.getAmounts().size() + "");
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(category);
            Log.d("DatabaseHandler","add or update : " + category);
        }
    });
    Log.e("test2",category.getAmounts().size() + "");
}

E/test: 31
D/DatabaseHandler: add or update : Category  id : 7 - label : Fast food 
& restaurants  - income : false - defaultBudget : 50.0 - archived : 
false - amounts : 0 - automaticTransactions : 0
E/test2: 0
```

Thanks for your help, I'm really stuck.

Comment: I assume it's because you're overwriting the existing object with a new object that has empty RealmList fields

Comment: I pass the amounts from the old category to the new one, If you look at the tests, you can see that the new Category has indeed 31 amounts.
It's just after the transaction that the Category loose it's amounts.
It doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: At first glance I'm not sure, so all I can recommend is to debug `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` call and see what it does internally and when it might call `nativeClear()`. Also, what version of Realm is this?

Comment: I've got realm 3.2.
So I've debbugged `copyToReamOrUpdate()` and indeed, nativeClear() is called in amountsRealmList.clear() : [see a screenshot here](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=985320realm.png).
Why it does that? Is it a bug? Because if it's clear the list every time, the for loop after is useless isn't it?
So how can I update my category without loosing the list?

Comment: can you test with Realm `3.7.2`? it might be related to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/5023

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still not working...

Comment: You might actually be running into https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5395 and apparently it's a bug. :|

Comment: Yes that's it! I hope it will be fixed soon.